# What are my food supply options sailing the Cyclades?

Tags: food-and-drink, greece, sailing, cyclades-islands

We are going on a two week sailing trip through the Cyclades, and I was told that we have to stow all the foodstuff we will need for those two weeks on depature, at Lavrio, because "there are no shops at the Cyclades islands". While this is not a problem with drinks, oil or potatoes, I feel uncomfortable with weeks-old bread, fruit, vegetables, or fish. What are my options?

First, is it true that there are no shops at the Cyclades islands? I almost cannot believe this. There are townships on these islands, there are people, there are harbours, there must be some regular food supply. However, at least Google Maps does not show any hits for παντοπωλείο (grocery).

What about markets? Is there a way to obtain a list when and where markets take place in the region, or is there a rule of thumb?

Any other suggestions? Do I have to stow a fishing rod, and some flour and yeast and bake my own bread on board (given the caboose has an oven)?

Comment: Is there any islands in perticular you are looking at? According to https://www.xo.gr/dir-az/S/Supermarkets/Ermoupoli%20Syros/?lang=en Ermoupoli (as far as I can tell - the largest city) has 10 supermarkets.

Comment: I'm not sure where you got this information from but this is totally false. You will have no problem findind the food items you need in the Cyclades.

Comment: Who told you that "there are no shops at the Cyclades islands"? This is totally ridiculous. Every Island has at least 1 town with shops and everything. You can even find rare delicatessen stuff in some.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the term supermarkets instead of grocery into Google maps - doing this seems to provide some hits for most of the islands.

[image: Google maps screenshot of Cyclades (Greece) islands]

Comment: Thank you. After your findings, I tried some more. Obviously Google Maps is language-sensitive here. I am using a web browser in German, and neither Greek nor English search for neither grocery nor supermaket showed these results. Surprisingly, searching in German yields the results as you found them.